# How to insert data into bytea in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I would like to store in the bytea column in PostgresQL following Data:
Name, Surname, Text, Something More

The presented data are 4 strings. How should I do an Insert command in SQL to be able to do it?

Comment: Why would you want to store "names" as binary data? That is most certainly the wrong data type. What is the real problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: I need to be able to store some templates in database. Every template can have other fields, so I would like to store all the fields in an object, or bytea or jsonb.

Comment: And then in Java I would like to ask the DB for example by id of the template to get all the data gathered in this particular template. Then I will know that using this template means for example that I should have fields like Name, Surname or whatever

Comment: Use `jsonb` instead

Comment: This depend on your driver/connection library.  Please tag the one you use.  Assuming you want to do this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to be able to store some templates in database

`bytea` is definitely the wrong choice for that. It's intended for binary data (images, PDF, etc).

You are trying to store semi-structured (but dynamic) data. `jsonb` is the correct choice for that.

Something along the lines:

```
insert into template (id, template_name, template_fields) 
values 
(1, 'person', '{"firstName": "string", "lastName": "string", "dateOfBirth": "date", "salary": "integer"}');
```